# NoClassDefFoundError in Sendgrid

Tags: java, sendgrid

I am using https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java in my app. This is my code

```
SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("username", "password");
SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();
email.addTo("user@domain.com");
email.setFrom("another@domain.com");
email.setSubject("Hello World");
email.setText("My first email with SendGrid Java!");

try {
  SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
  System.out.println(response.getMessage());
}
catch (SendGridException e) {
  System.err.println(e);
}
```

This is my maven code

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
<artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

While running this code I get the following error.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

Root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder
com.sendgrid.SendGrid.<init>(SendGrid.java:67)
```

I am new to java, I dont know what this means. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in maven dependency for sendgrid. So I just copied the class from the https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java to my app. There was only two class in it. Also I copied the dependency from the sendgrid-java and added to my app. It worked.

Comment: Is there still an issue with the maven dependency? Because I'm experiencing the same at the moment (worked before thou)

Comment: @Perneel Now this is fixed, I tried today, its working fine. Just add the jar file and start sending email

Comment: @Subash what version are you running? I tried it with 2.2.2 and i get the NoClassDefFoundException

Comment: @DeiAndrei Use 2.2.1 I have tested that, it is working fine

Comment: I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundException` using 2.2.1 with Gradle.

Comment: There may of been issues that long ago with the dependencies that require this force fix - not sure, too long ago, but if you get it now it's likely due to the problem I've mentioned.

Comment: @Subash what two classes did you add?

Comment: @dopatraman now they are having only one class, use that and also add it's dependency

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler`for `sendgrid-java 4.4.1` .. any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing a mvn dependency:tree and scanning your tree for the following class: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

I am migrating from Mandrill to SendGrid and the reason is that my mandril dependency was 'higher' in the list than my sendgrid-java dependency, and Mandrill used a version 4.2 of the httpclient artifact.

My fix was to add an exclusion to remove that artifact from Mandrill

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
        <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Obviously for you it might be different, but I'm willing to bet you're dependency is bringing in an older version f the http client.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This adds missing dependencies to your code. The error you got was because your code missed dependencies that are used in yet another dependency. If you still have a problem understanding your error I suggest you read up on dependency management in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved.
I have moved the maven dependency from a service/pom.xml to the parent module pom.xml

mvn dependency:tree to see the dependency in each module

only using the followinng dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
    <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async Task<bool> CreateMailItem(string email, string name, string subject, string body)
    {
        string SendGridEmail = _configuration.GetSection("EmailSendGrid:Email").Value;
        string APIKey = _configuration.GetSection("EmailSendGrid:Key").Value;
        
        SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(APIKey);
        EmailAddress from = new EmailAddress(SendGridEmail, "Teste de Envio");            
        EmailAddress to = new EmailAddress(email, name);
        SendGridMessage msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, "", body);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).